# 500 Internal Server Error in Azure AD B2C Password Reset Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

When I try to execute our PasswordReset(custom policy) policy from the Azure Portal, I'm getting

**500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.**

but our signInSignUp Policy is working fine.

How to find out what went wrong with PasswordReset Policy?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is lacking sufficient detail to help the community help you.

Comment: As soon as I click "Run Now" button on the PasswordReset Policy from Azure Portal, I am getting the above mentioned error.

Comment: Are you still seeing the issue? Can you try opening the link in the Private window or any other browser and check?

Comment: I cleared cache and tried in Private window, still seeing the error. I am not sure of the ways to find out what went wrong

Comment: could it be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48896245/500-internal-server-error-in-azure-ad-b2c)?

Comment: Thanks spottedmahn, Issue is similar to that. I added an outputclaim for returning identityProvider in the IdToken and the policy is not able to figure out the value of that. I assigned a defaultValue to that claim and now it is working.

Comment: FYI: "The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: `@peter` or `@PeterSmith` will both work."

Comment: Cool.  You should post that as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

I added an outputclaim for returning identityProvider in the IdToken and the policy is not able to figure out the value of that. I assigned a defaultValue to that claim and now it is working